# Does there exist an open interval $U$ such that $\mu(A\cap U)>0$ and $\mu(A^c\cap U)=0$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space where $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $ \mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.  Take and open interval $O\supset A$, $\mu(A)>0$ and $B=O\setminus A$.

Does there exist an open interval $U$ such that $\mu(A\cap U)>0$ and $\mu(B\cap U)=0$?

As you may have guessed, I am very much a beginner at this. I know that in general (e.g. A is a Cantor set with positive measure) there will not exist a $U, \mu(U)>0$ such that $(B\cap U)$ is an empty set but it seems like we should be able to satisfy $\mu(B\cap U)=0$ by expressing $O$ as a countable union of pair-wise disjoint open intervals $O_i$ such that
$$ O=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i$$
Then
$$\mu(O)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(O_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A\cap O_i) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(B\cap O_i)$$

So the crux seems to be, for at least one of the summands, can the following be proved to hold?
$$\mu(O_i) =\mu(A\cap O_i) \Rightarrow \mu(B\cap O_i)=0$$

Comment: Since your new here, just thought I'd say that this is a nicely posed question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take A to be a Cantor set of positive measure. Then B is open. Since the intersection of any open interval U with B is open and nonempty, the intersection will have positive measure, of course. Therefore, the answer is NO.

Comment: I can't argue with your answer, but perhaps you can help me get unstuck.  Refer to the def of $\mu$ above, if every $I_n$ still spans some measurable part of B, doesn't countable additivity fail?

Comment: @user102569: Review your basic calculus: A series can converge to a positive real number even if all terms are nonzero!